# Track logs of a specific wallet address not emitting anything

Tags: web3js

I am trying to track a wallet address and whenever it does something to emit an event.
This is for BSC btw

Here is the code

```
 var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
        address: '0x6F8Baf6076604A7b5e56d2C082bc9c205525Db84',
     
    }, function(error, result){
        if (!error)
            console.log(result);
    }).on("data", function(e){
        console.log("p" + e)
    }).on("error", function(e){
        console.log("p" + e)
    });
```

When I send a test transfer, nothing emits.

But if I subscribe to ALL transactions, then compare each to the desired address, it works.

I don't want to subscribe to all transaction and am wondering if there is a way to listen to a specific wallet transactions only.

Answer (score 0):

I also looked for a solution for a single address, but unfortunately there is no solution. I'm adding this here for those who happen to pass by.

```
async function listenTransaction(receiver, callback) {
    // Web3 provider needs to be websockets
    let balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(receiver);
    let subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders');

    subscription.on("data", async (blockHeader) => {
        let newbalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(receiver);
        if (balance < newbalance) {
            balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(receiver);
            let currentBlock = await web3.eth.getBlock(blockHeader.hash, true);
            currentBlock.transactions.forEach(transaction => {
                if (transaction.to && transaction.to.toLowerCase() == receiver.toLowerCase()) {
                    callback(transaction.hash, subscription);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```